# How to recalculate an array of object from nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects where Citems is an array of Objects. Each object has status on or off and time.

```
[
{
  Chapter: [
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 1',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'on', time: 60}],
      
    },
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 2',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'off', time: 60}]
    }
  ],
  name: 'Something',
  description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
},{
  Chapter: [
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 1',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'on', time: 60}],
      
    },
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 2',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'off', time: 60}]
    }
  ],
  name: 'Something',
  description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
},{
  Chapter: [
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 1',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'on', time: 60}],
      
    },
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 2',
      Citems: [{status: 'on', time: 30},{status: 'off', time: 60}]
    }
  ],
  name: 'Something',
  description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
}
]
```

I want to generate an array or object from it that show total time for each status like below

```
[{
on: 120,
off: 60
},
{
on: 120,
off: 60
},
{
on: 120,
off: 60
}]
```

I tried to use map and reduce in it by not getting the derired result

Comment: Are the `CName`s (chapters) sorted? With this `[{on: 120, off: 60}, {on: 120, off: 60}, {on: 120, off: 60}]` how do you figure out which object corresponds to which chapter?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track using `map()` and `reduce()`. An additional call to [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) brings it all together:

```
const result = data.map(({ Chapter }) => Chapter
  .flatMap(({ Citems }) => Citems)
  .reduce((a, { status, time }) => ({
    ...a,
    [status]: (a[status] || 0) + time
  }), {})
);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  Chapter: [{
      Cname: 'chapter 1',
      Citems: [{
        status: 'on',
        time: 30
      }, {
        status: 'on',
        time: 60
      }],

    },
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 2',
      Citems: [{
        status: 'on',
        time: 30
      }, {
        status: 'off',
        time: 60
      }]
    }
  ],
  name: 'Something',
  description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
}, {
  Chapter: [{
      Cname: 'chapter 1',
      Citems: [{
        status: 'on',
        time: 30
      }, {
        status: 'on',
        time: 60
      }],

    },
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 2',
      Citems: [{
        status: 'on',
        time: 30
      }, {
        status: 'off',
        time: 60
      }]
    }
  ],
  name: 'Something',
  description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
}, {
  Chapter: [{
      Cname: 'chapter 1',
      Citems: [{
        status: 'on',
        time: 30
      }, {
        status: 'on',
        time: 60
      }],

    },
    {
      Cname: 'chapter 2',
      Citems: [{
        status: 'on',
        time: 30
      }, {
        status: 'off',
        time: 60
      }]
    }
  ],
  name: 'Something',
  description: 'jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd'
}];

const result = data.map(({ Chapter }) => Chapter
  .flatMap(({ Citems }) => Citems)
  .reduce((a, { status, time }) => ({
    ...a,
    [status]: (a[status] || 0) + time
  }), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it using `map` and `flatMap`.

```
data.map(({ Chapter }) => {
  let on = 0;
  let off = 0;

  Chapter.flatMap(({ Citems }) => Citems).map((item) => {
    if (item.status === "on") {
      on += item.time;
    } else {
      off += item.time;
    }
  });

  return { on, off };
});
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    Chapter: [
      {
        Cname: "chapter 1",
        Citems: [
          { status: "on", time: 30 },
          { status: "on", time: 60 }
        ]
      },
      {
        Cname: "chapter 2",
        Citems: [
          { status: "on", time: 30 },
          { status: "off", time: 60 }
        ]
      }
    ],
    name: "Something",
    description: "jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd"
  },
  {
    Chapter: [
      {
        Cname: "chapter 1",
        Citems: [
          { status: "on", time: 30 },
          { status: "on", time: 60 }
        ]
      },
      {
        Cname: "chapter 2",
        Citems: [
          { status: "on", time: 30 },
          { status: "off", time: 60 }
        ]
      }
    ],
    name: "Something",
    description: "jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd"
  },
  {
    Chapter: [
      {
        Cname: "chapter 1",
        Citems: [
          { status: "on", time: 30 },
          { status: "on", time: 60 }
        ]
      },
      {
        Cname: "chapter 2",
        Citems: [
          { status: "on", time: 30 },
          { status: "off", time: 60 }
        ]
      }
    ],
    name: "Something",
    description: "jfdgljfgdfjgldfkjglfd"
  }
];

const result = data.map(({ Chapter }) => {
  let on = 0;
  let off = 0;

  Chapter.flatMap(({ Citems }) => Citems).map((item) => {
    if (item.status === "on") {
      on += item.time;
    } else {
      off += item.time;
    }
  });

  return { on, off };
});

console.log(result);
```